# How can I transfer tables from one SQL Server database to another?

Tags: sql-server, visual-web-developer, mdf

I have 2 SQL Server database files .mdf on 2 different projects in Visual Web Developer Express Edition 2010, I need to make them one database by taking the tables of one database to the other database.

I use the built in development server of Web Developer and I don't have SQL Server installed separately on my system.

So how can I do that ? Do I need special tools or this can be done with web developer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the database publishing wizard. It should let you generate scripts for the entire database and then you can just run those scripts in your new db.